# Various background images failing to load via CSS stylesheet in Shopify

Tags: css, background-image, shopify, liquid

I am having a very strange problem that I can't seem to figure out.

I have several images that I am using as background images in the style sheet `galleria-fullscreen.css.liquid`. For some reason, some of the images load and some do not. They are all located in the assets folder in Shopify, and there is really no rhyme or reason why some of them are loading and some are failing.

I have tried using the following:

```
background: url( {{'down.gif'}} );

background: url('down.gif');

background: url( {{'down.gif'}} | asset_url );
```

None of these changes seem to do anything.

I think the best thing to do is take a look at the page in firebug and see for yourself.

https://fine-grain-2.myshopify.com/products/the-bowden-brown-cherry#

I will post the relevant code as well below.

Here is the CSS pertinent to the problem:

This image loads:

```
.galleria-thumbnails-tab {
    opacity: .7;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    top: 0;
    height: 16px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #DADAD2 url( {{'up.gif'}} ) no-repeat 50% 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
```

These images don't load:

```
.galleria-thumbnails-tab.open,
.galleria-thumbnails-tab.open:hover {
    background: url( {{'down.gif'}} );
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.galleria-image-nav-right,
.galleria-image-nav-left {
    width: 100px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: url( "{{'arrow-right.png'}}" ) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}
.galleria-image-nav-left {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    background-image: url( "{{'arrow-left.png'}}"  );
}
```

Comment: Why are your background-image URL's in double brackets? Is that a shopify thing? Also when you inspect your website do you get any 404 errors on your images under the network tab?

Comment: It is not a Shopify thing, and I will check for 404's in network.

Comment: The normal CSS syntax for a background-image is `background-image:url('../pathtoimage/image.jpg');` So unless `{{'image'}}` is part of the templating structure, chances are that is why your images are not loading.

Comment: Yeah liquid uses a strange structure, so it is part of the liquid aspect of things.

Comment: I am getting 404's for the background images that do not load. What should I do?

Comment: Double check the syntax and paths for your background URLS. 404 means it isn't finding the resource. Here is an article on Shopify CSS syntax http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/images-url-s-in-the-style-css-file-109049

Comment: I just checked them all one by one and they are all exactly how shopify says to make them. This is so weird because it is only random images that are not loading.

Comment: So you have something like this `#selector {background: url( {{'down.gif' | asset_url }}) };` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would double check the syntax of your css `backround-image`. Make sure it follows the proper templating syntax for shopify.

Double check Network Tab in web inspector. If you have 404's for specific images then double check the syntax and paths to make sure you are properly loading the images.

**Try this syntax:**

It looks like you  are missing `| asset_url` or didn't put it inside the double closing brackets.

```
#selector {background:url({{ 'image.jpg' | asset_url }});}
```

**SOME INFO ON SHOPIFY LIQUID LAYOUT / CSS URL FORMATTING:**

http://wiki.shopify.com/Asset_url

http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/images-url-s-in-the-style-css-file-109049

http://wiki.shopify.com/Liquid

Comment: I actually ended up just changing the image filenames and they started loading correctly, but without your help I wouldn't have tried so many options. Thanks!